Почему выходят сразу 10 элементов?
Как правильно перебрать элементы, чтобы выбирался один элемент?
Есть модальное окно. При наведении на Постер появляются все модалки. Как сделать так, чтобы выходила определенная модалка и удалялась, когда уводишь курсор?


"use strict";
const CheckTextForNum = document.querySelector(".text"),
  body = document.querySelector("body"),
  moviePoster = document.querySelectorAll(".item"),
  block1 = document.querySelector("div.block-D-none"),
  blockClose = document.querySelector("div.close-opening-window"),
  windowClose = document.querySelector(".closeWindow"),
  divMovieContainer = document.querySelector("div.container-postr"),
  templatePostr = document.querySelector(".movie-content").content;



divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  const parent = event.target.closest('div.container-postr');
  const posters =
    parent.querySelectorAll('div.block-D-none');
  for (const block of posters) {
    block.classList.add("block");
    block.classList.remove("block-D-none");
  }

});


divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
  const parent = event.target.closest('div.container-postr');
  const posters =
    parent.querySelectorAll('div.block-D-none');
  for (const block of posters) {
    block.classList.remove("block");
    block.classList.add("block-D-none");
  }

});



showPostr();

async function showPostr() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/");
    const users = await response.json();
    createNameMovie(users);
  } catch (error) {
    showErr(error);
  }
}

function showErr(err) {
  body.innerHTML = `<span class="error">ERROR:${err}</span>`;
}

function createNameMovie(users) {
  for (let user of users) {
    const fragment = templatePostr.cloneNode(true);
    fragment.querySelector(".name-movie").textContent = user.username;
    fragment.querySelector(".date-movie").textContent = "Date: " + user.id;
    divMovieContainer.append(fragment);
  }
}
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  background-image: url(movie-background-collage.jpg);
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrap-center {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

header>ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 0 .2em .3em .6em;
}

header>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}

header>ul>li>a:hover {
  padding-bottom: .6em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px blue;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

header>ul>li {
  padding: 0 .5em 0 .4em;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  color: black;
}

.icon-logo {
  padding-right: .5em;
}

.group-logo {
  margin: .3em 0;
  margin-left: .6em;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  margin: .5em;
}

.group-search {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: none;
  margin: .3em 0;
  margin-right: .6em;
}

.group-poisk {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.story {
  height: 31px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px blue;
  border-radius: 11px;
  padding-left: .7em;
  font-size: large;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: none;
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search-btn {
  top: 28px;
  right: 310px;
  position: absolute;
  /* background-color: white; */
}

.desc-text {
  background-color: rgb(208, 206, 206);
  padding: .2em 0 1em .6em;
}

.name-site {
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.text-color {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: .8em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* border-radius: 10%; */
}

.kino-poster-img {
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.container-postr {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  width: 33.33%;
  margin: .5em .7em;
}

.url-movie {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.name-group-movie {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.name-movie {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: calc(14px + 2 * ((100vw - 420px) / 860));
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

.date-movie {
  margin: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(39, 39, 137, 0.868);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.error {
  color: black;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(9, 9, 54);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 0em;
}

.group-logo-foot {
  margin-left: .6em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.foot-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 1em;
  font-size: larger;
}

.foot-menu>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: '›';
}

.foot-menu>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 .6em;
  color: white;
}

ul>li {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
  color: blue;
}


/* window modal*/

span {
  user-select: none;
}

button {
  user-select: none;
}

.block-D-none {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  transform: translate(-33%, -33%);
  width: 125px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.closeWindow {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: black;
}

@media(min-width:770px) {
  .item {
    width: 25%;
  }
  footer {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .group-logo-foot {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1025px) {
  .group-search,
  header>ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .item {
    width: 15.66%;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wink.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap-center">
      <header>
        <div class="group-logo">
          <a class="logo" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/film">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/serial">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/multfilm">Мультфильмы</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="group-search">
          <div class="group-poisk">
            <input class="story form__email" type="text" value="red">
            <span class="btn-search form__btn"><img src="ico-poisk.png" alt=""></span>
          </div>
          <button class="login openModalWindow">Войти</button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="container-postr">

        </div>
      </main>
      <div class="desc-text">
        <h3><span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> – фильмы в HD онлайн бесплатно и без регистрации!</h3>
        <span>Современный портал nazfilm вас точно порадует: на сайте собраны тысячи фильмов,
        которые можно просматривать онлайн в высоком качестве. Удобный,
        простой и комфортный «кинотеатр на дому» предлагает смотреть новинки совершенно бесплатно,
        то есть значительно экономит ваше время и деньги на поиск кинозала и покупку билетов.
        Фильмы, представленные на сайте, рассортированы по категориям и жанрам: Лордфильм регулярно добавляет не только популярные киноленты,
        но и сериалы, и мультфильмы в приятной озвучке и хорошем качестве.
        Смотреть кино можно круглосуточно и в любой точке мира – мы публикуем новинки,
        которые помогут отдохнуть после тяжелых будней и еще раз встретиться с любимыми героями.
        Официальный сайт Лорд Фильм дает возможность смотреть любимые фильмы и сериалы с любого устройства.
        Это может быть компьютер, планшет, а также смартфон на IOS или Android.
        Умный проигрыватель определит оптимальный режим просмотра для вашего девайса,
        а вам останется только подобрать увлекательные фильмы онлайн из огромного архива и наслаждаться просмотром!</span>
      </div>


      <footer>
        <div class="group-logo-foot">
          <a class="logo text-color" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a>
          <span>
       <span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> - сайт Назфильм онлайн в хорошем качестве бесплатно.
          <br>
          <a class="text-color" href="https://mail.ru/po" target="_blank">boss.fataliev@mail.ru</a> - почта для обратной связи.
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="foot-menu">
          <p>Главное меню</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Фильмы</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Сериалы</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <template class="movie-content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="date-movie"></div>
        <a class="url-movie" href="https://mo.lordfilm15.com/filmy/51352-chuzhoj-romul-2024.html" target="_blank"> 
            <img class="poster-img" src="kino-poster.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="name-group-movie">
            <h3 class="name-movie"></h3>
        </div>
        
            
            <!--open window-->
            <div class="block-D-none close-opening-window">
                <div class="block2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
    </div>
</template>
  <script src="wink.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Как-то получилось, все работает, но почему-то выдает ошибку
divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
const parent = event.target.closest("div.item");
let group = parent.querySelector("div.close-opening-window");
group.classList.remove("block-D-none");
group.classList.add("block");
});
divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
const parent = event.target.closest("div.item");
let group = parent.querySelector("div.close-opening-window");
group.classList.remove("block");
group.classList.add("block-D-none");
});

Например так. Работает, но там верстку сначала надо нормально сделать, чтобы не прыгали "модалки".


"use strict";
const CheckTextForNum = document.querySelector(".text"),
    body = document.querySelector("body"),
    moviePoster = document.querySelectorAll(".item"),
    block1 = document.querySelector("div.block-D-none"),
    blockClose = document.querySelector("div.close-opening-window"),
    windowClose = document.querySelector(".closeWindow"),
    divMovieContainer = document.querySelector("div.container-postr"),
    templatePostr = document.querySelector(".movie-content").content;



divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
    // const parent = event.target.closest('div.container-postr');
    // const posters =
    //     parent.querySelectorAll('div.block-D-none');
    // for (const block of posters) {
    //     block.classList.add("block");
    //     block.classList.remove("block-D-none");
    // }

    if (event.target !== divMovieContainer) {
        const modal = event.target.closest('.item').querySelector('.close-opening-window');
        modal.classList.add('block');
        modal.classList.remove('block-D-none');
    }

});


divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
    // const parent = event.target.closest('div.container-postr');
    // const posters =
    //     parent.querySelectorAll('div.block-D-none');
    // for (const block of posters) {
    //     block.classList.remove("block");
    //     block.classList.add("block-D-none");
    // }

    if (event.target !== divMovieContainer) {
        const modal = event.target.closest('.item').querySelector('.close-opening-window');
        modal.classList.remove('block');
        modal.classList.add('block-D-none');
    }
});

showPostr();

async function showPostr () {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/");
        const users = await response.json();
        createNameMovie(users);
    } catch (error) {
        showErr(error);
    }
}

function showErr (err) {
    body.innerHTML = `<span class="error">ERROR:${err}</span>`;
}

function createNameMovie (users) {
    for (let user of users) {
        const fragment = templatePostr.cloneNode(true);
        fragment.querySelector(".name-movie").textContent = user.username;
        fragment.querySelector(".date-movie").textContent = "Date: " + user.id;
        divMovieContainer.append(fragment);
    }
}
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
    background-image: url(movie-background-collage.jpg);
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    min-width: 320px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
}

.wrap-center {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
}

header>ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 0 .2em .3em .6em;
}

header>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}

header>ul>li>a:hover {
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px blue;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

header>ul>li {
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .4em;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: black;
}

.icon-logo {
    padding-right: .5em;
}

.group-logo {
    margin: .3em 0;
    margin-left: .6em;
}

.btn-search {
    position: absolute;
    margin: .5em;
}

.group-search {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: none;
    margin: .3em 0;
    margin-right: .6em;
}

.group-poisk {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.story {
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px blue;
    border-radius: 11px;
    padding-left: .7em;
    font-size: large;
}

.login {
    margin-left: 1em;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-size: large;
    color: white;
}

.login:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-btn {
    top: 28px;
    right: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    /* background-color: white; */
}

.desc-text {
    background-color: rgb(208, 206, 206);
    padding: .2em 0 1em .6em;
}

.name-site {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.text-color {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* border-radius: 10%; */
}

.kino-poster-img {
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    background-color: #ededed;
}

.container-postr {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 6px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    width: 33.33%;
    margin: .5em .7em;
}

.url-movie {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}

.name-group-movie {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.name-movie {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: calc(14px + 2 * ((100vw - 420px) / 860));
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
}

.date-movie {
    margin: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(39, 39, 137, 0.868);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.error {
    color: black;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(9, 9, 54);
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 0em;
}

.group-logo-foot {
    margin-left: .6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.foot-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 1em;
    font-size: larger;
}

.foot-menu>ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    list-style-type: '›';
}

.foot-menu>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 .6em;
    color: white;
}

ul>li {
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
    color: blue;
}


/* window modal*/

span {
    user-select: none;
}

button {
    user-select: none;
}

.block-D-none {
    display: none;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    transform: translate(-33%, -33%);
    width: 125px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.block2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.closeWindow {
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vh;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: black;
}

@media(min-width:770px) {
    .item {
        width: 25%;
    }

    footer {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .group-logo-foot {
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
}

@media(min-width:1025px) {

    .group-search,
    header>ul {
        display: flex;
    }

    .item {
        width: 15.66%;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wink.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-center">
            <header>
                <div class="group-logo">
                    <a class="logo" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/film">Фильмы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/serial">Сериалы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/multfilm">Мультфильмы</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="group-search">
                    <div class="group-poisk">
                        <input class="story form__email" type="text" value="red">
                        <span class="btn-search form__btn"><img src="ico-poisk.png" alt=""></span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="login openModalWindow">Войти</button>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="container-postr">

                </div>
            </main>
            <div class="desc-text">
                <h3><span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> – фильмы в HD онлайн бесплатно и без регистрации!</h3>
                <span>Современный портал nazfilm вас точно порадует: на сайте собраны тысячи фильмов,
                    которые можно просматривать онлайн в высоком качестве. Удобный,
                    простой и комфортный «кинотеатр на дому» предлагает смотреть новинки совершенно бесплатно,
                    то есть значительно экономит ваше время и деньги на поиск кинозала и покупку билетов.
                    Фильмы, представленные на сайте, рассортированы по категориям и жанрам: Лордфильм регулярно
                    добавляет не только популярные киноленты,
                    но и сериалы, и мультфильмы в приятной озвучке и хорошем качестве.
                    Смотреть кино можно круглосуточно и в любой точке мира – мы публикуем новинки,
                    которые помогут отдохнуть после тяжелых будней и еще раз встретиться с любимыми героями.
                    Официальный сайт Лорд Фильм дает возможность смотреть любимые фильмы и сериалы с любого устройства.
                    Это может быть компьютер, планшет, а также смартфон на IOS или Android.
                    Умный проигрыватель определит оптимальный режим просмотра для вашего девайса,
                    а вам останется только подобрать увлекательные фильмы онлайн из огромного архива и наслаждаться
                    просмотром!</span>
            </div>


            <footer>
                <div class="group-logo-foot">
                    <a class="logo text-color" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a>
                    <span>
                        <span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> - сайт Назфильм онлайн в хорошем качестве бесплатно.
                        <br>
                        <a class="text-color" href="https://mail.ru/po" target="_blank">boss.fataliev@mail.ru</a> -
                        почта для обратной связи.
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="foot-menu">
                    <p>Главное меню</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Фильмы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Сериалы</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <template class="movie-content">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="date-movie"></div>
            <a class="url-movie" href="https://mo.lordfilm15.com/filmy/51352-chuzhoj-romul-2024.html" target="_blank">
                <img class="poster-img" src="kino-poster.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="name-group-movie">
                    <h3 class="name-movie"></h3>
                </div>


                <!--open window-->
                <div class="block-D-none close-opening-window">
                    <div class="block2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script src="wink.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Спасибо,  ТЫ лучший
